# Limit a folder browser dialog to only folders containing specific files

Tags: c#, winforms, folderbrowserdialog

I have a folder browser dialog (simple enough) but I only want it to be 'ok' if the folder contains files of a certain extension. What I have so far:

```
FolderBrowserDialog pDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
if (pDlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    if (Directory.GetFiles(pDlg.SelectedPath, "*.ext").Length > 0)
    {
        SrcDir.Text = pDlg.SelectedPath;
    }
    else
    {
        DBox.Items.Insert(0, "Not a suitable folder");
    }
}
```

This works in limiting the population of the textbox `SrcDir` if the selected folder does not contain any of the right sort of files (*.ext). It would be preferable if I could disable the 'ok' button when the folder is selected in the dialog if `GetFiles(..).Length == 0` so an unsuitable folder just cannot be selected; as you cannot 'see' the files in the `FolderBrowserDialog` it's kind of hard for the user to know if it is the right folder, so by changing the `enabled` state of the OK button would indicate to the user if the folder is suitable.

I could use a [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) to browse for one file in the directory and then use [FileInfo.DirectoryName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48ywhe1a(v=vs.110).aspx) to extract the folder that its in, but I am under pressure *not* to do it that way (others think it's sloppy).

I am fairly sure this can't be done with a standard `FolderBrowserDialog`; is there another in-built dialog class that I can control this behavior or should I create a new form with a `DirectorySearcher` or similar TreeView and `.ShowDialog()` on a custom dialog form?

Comment: I believe powershell might be a better option for file/folder management...

Comment: @Ben, I've heard that name before but I am not aware of what it is. Do you have a link to a help page/tutorial so I can see if it's applicable.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) is the wiki entry about it. It's a scripting tool, used to manage folder operations (for example) when run. TechNet also has some [basic tutorials](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx) to get you started

Comment: Consider building your own dialog using treeview and listbox. Samples abound on build a file "explorer."

Comment: Yeh, @rheitzman, I think that's going to be my only option. I can't install more libs on the users' computers so I'm limited to just .net framework. I was hoping there was an obscure browser dialog that did have this functionality so save myself a few hours designing, coding and debugging a custom dialog.